# Radius of convergence $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+a^{n})z^{n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

hi could you please help me find the radius of convergence for the next series

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+a^{n})z^{n}$

please i have tried by the quotient criterion and using the hardy formula but i did not come to any conclusion and put it into wolfram but i dont know how  get to the result it throws.

Comment: Start with $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+a^{n})z^{n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} nz^n + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^n z^n$

Comment: Yes, thanks, I has blocked, but thanks to your hint, i got it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n z^n = z \left(\frac{d}{dz} \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n\right)$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n z^n =   \sum_{n=0}^\infty (az)^n$$

The first series has radius of convergence $R_1 = 1$, and the second series has radius of convergence $R_2 = \frac{1}{|a|}$.  Therefore, the radius of convergence is $$R = \min\left\{1, \frac{1}{|a|}\right\}.$$